# AS3 - Defining functions inside of other functions

Tags: actionscript-3

When adding event listeners and defining their corresponding functions I find myself defining the function in the code of a constructor a lot. Something like this:

```
package
    {
        public class stuff extends Sprite
        {
            public function stuff()
            {
                minimizeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, minimizeOnClick);
                function minimizeOnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
                {
                       //do minimization stuff here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, there is clearly another option to define it like any other method of the class. Something like this:

```
 package
    {
        public class stuff extends Sprite
        {
            public function stuff()
            {
                minimizeBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, minimizeOnClick);
            }

            internal function minimizeOnClick(e:MouseEvent):void
            {
                //do minimization stuff here
            }
        }
    }
```

The second option may not really make sense because the function isn't really a method of the class. But my concern is that the first method will use up extra memory for each instance of the class. Which is the most efficient and correct way to do this and also does the first method take up extra memory or CPU time for each instance of the class?

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you would want to have the constructor as simple as possible (if you need to do a lot of things call an init() private method you define) and having the listener(minimizeOnClick) as a private function is the simplest solution in my opinion

Comment: Thanks George. I've seen other people say keep the constructor simple as well. Is there a reason for this other than code readability? Using an init function just adds more overhead (only a few CPU cycles so its almost nothing, but still). Do constructors in AS do something significantly different than C or Java constructors?

Comment: According to [Joa Ebert](http://blog.joa-ebert.com/) in [ActionScript 3 optimization techniques](http://je2050.joa-ebert.com/files/misc/as3opt.pdf) "Code inside the constructor is not optimized by the Just-in-time compiler (JIT). To use JIT optimized code there is the possibility to call a function out of the constructor. The code inside that function is then optimized again.". In short the Actionscript Virtual Machine(AVM) works differently than C/Java

Comment: As stated above constructors should have minimal code in it usually just one line calling an init stle function. Nesting functions in my opinion should never be used it can create a plethora of issues such as losing scope. I would suggest you grab flexPMD and run it on somed of your files. It will keep you in check with standard coding practices. http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexpmd/FlexPMD+Eclipse+plugin

Comment: I can back all the stuff mentioned above as well, I normally don't use constructors and instead have my own `construct()` method.

Comment: Function inside of the function creates closure (it can access local variables of the outer function) and is significantly slower to call, so concerns about CPU and memory are not ungrounded :)

Answer (score 1):

The latter example is the correct way, and it's true that you should try encapsulate your `addEventListener()` and listening function within the relevant class. In your case, you may want to consider making a class for your `minimizeBtn`:

```
public class MinimizeButton extends SimpleButton
{

    public function MinimizeButton()
    {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _onClick);
    }

    private function _onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        // do minimization stuff here
    }

}
```

`MinimizeButton`'s  `_onClick()` should then target the relevant instance of your class `stuff` and run whatever `stuff` needs to do from there.

This example's process is more like:

`MinimizeButton:` "I've been clicked, I should inform `stuff` so it can do something relevant."

Rather than:

`stuff:` "I'm going to sit and wait for `MinimizeButton` to get clicked, then I'll do what's required."